# JMeter - add additional SSLCipher(s) to jmeter

Tags: ssl, https, jmeter

Our https application doesn't support any of the SSLCiphers which are currently available with jmeter. I want to add some extra cipher methods to jmeter. How to achieve this?

I searched on internet and only found the relevant question [here](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/How-can-i-add-new-SSLCipher-to-jmeter-td4749728.html#none). But not useful since it's not answered.

I checked packets coming from jmeter using wireshark and seen the client request's cipher list which doesn't contain any of cipher which are supported by our application. The same thing is working if I request through firefox browser.

JMeter version: 2.13 (r1665067)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cipher which I was looking for was in the list of [java 7,8 cipher suites](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html). The [footnote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#footnote1-1) says about upgrading to TLSv1.2 for Java 7.

So for upgrading it, go to bin/jmeter.properties uncomment below line and do changes as below.

```
https.default.protocol=TLSv1.2
```

Comment: Not accepting as default answer since, there are some more cipher suits in java which are disabled by default and if someone wants to use those in jmeter testing.

Comment: Those disabled cipher suites are insecure. Nobody should want to test them.